# jQuery Mobile app not scrolling in Firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox, jquery-mobile, desktop

I have a mobile app built in jQuery mobile. It is scrolling fine in Chrome & Safari, but fails to scroll in Firefox on Desktop. I have other instances of the same app, with slightly different features, and works across all browsers. For the life of me, I cannot figure this, please help!

Located here: http://re-brand.us/dsus/index.html

Comment: Hello , you brought Theme from Themenector For following page ? http://www.re-brand.us/

Comment: The "Smarty Mobile" theme was purchased from Themeforest.

Comment: But its bug of Firefox . What can you do about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be a bug in firefox: [Bug Log](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=927702). I am able to scroll using the keyboard but not with my trackpad on my mac.

Are you using a mac? I'll keep looking to see if I can find a way around it.

Comment: Yes I am using a Mac, however it fails on PC as well. I can scroll with my keyboard, but not the mouse. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hmmm that is weird. I'm looking into how you could have jQuery grab the scroll event and manually reposition the page. I'll ping you again if I figure it out.

Comment: Problem solved. The livetweet plugin had "overflow:hidden"

Once I removed that, scrolling returned!